# How do I upload a file from local to a webapp using webdriver with java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have to import an Excel file to a web application. To import 1st I have to click on an import btn, which will pop open another window that has the browse btn. Clicking on the browsebtn opens a OS dialogue box. I want to send the file path in this dialogue box then select the file and click upload. 
here is the code I am using for this:

```
String path="C:/excelFiles";
Robot robot;

WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(importExcelbtn));
importExcelbtn.click();
browseBtn.sendKeys(path);
wait(4);
browseBtn.click();

wait(4);


StringSelection sel=new StringSelection(excelFileToImport);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(sel,null);

System.out.println("File to upload:"+ sel);
robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
wait(3);            
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
okBtn.click();
} catch (AWTException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is, my code opens all the window, but it does not/cannot put the correct file path in the OS dialogue box so eventually the test fails. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After Clicking Import Button add this code. One more question, After modal dialog opens which button is focused like open/Cancel. Add a screenshot of modal dialog for better answer.

```
     setClipboardData("C:\\excelFiles");
     Robot robot = new Robot(); 
     robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
     robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
     robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     robot.delay(5000);

     public static void setClipboardData(String string) 
    {
       StringSelection StrSelect = new StringSelection(string);
       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(StrSelect, null);
    }
```